# This cat has bugs? Really?

Tags: code-golf, string, random

## Challenge:

Read input (within visible ASCII range) and output with a few modifications:

1. In each set of 10 characters of the input randomly (50/50):

   - replace one character* (with a random** one within visible ASCII range) (ex. `lumberjack` becomes `lumbeZjack`)
   - or remove one character (ex. `lumberjack` becomes `lmberjack`)

<sup>* If the set is of less than 10 characters, you don't have to modify it, but you can.</sup>
<sup>** The character can be the same as the one input, as long as it's still random.</sup>

## Example:

Input: `Go home cat! You're drunk!`
Output: `Go hom cat! YouLre drunk!`
(just a example, since output could be random, don't use as a test case)

## Rules:

- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), least characters wins!

Comment: @n4melyh4xor also you could post future challenges on the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). There you will get some feedback about your challenge.

Comment: What if the replacement char is the same as the char to be replaced?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills, I'm not that picky, it's fine.

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91584/42963)

Comment: Does the index of the character to be replaced have to be random?

Comment: Does it have to be uniformly random, or just each character just need a non-zero chance of appearing?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be at least 10 characters long?

Comment: @FlipTack "If the set is of less than 10 characters, you don't have to modify it, but you can." I would interpret that as a no.

Comment: Is it acceptable just to alter 10% of characters at random, or does it have to be exactly one in each group of 10 characters?

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
VczTpXNOT?<JOr\ \ÞKC127JK
```

[Test suite available here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VczTpXNOT%3F%3CJOr%5C+%5C%C3%9EKC127JK&input=Go+home+cat%21+You%27re+drunk%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=lumberjack%0AGo+home+cat%21+You%27re+drunk%21%0APerhaps+I+should+not+use+test+cases+from+the+question%2C+as+the+output+can+be+different+from+those+examples+and+still+be+correct%21&debug=0)

Thanks to [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103355/this-cat-has-bugs-really/103376#comment251583_103376) for shaving off 2 bytes.

## Explanation

```
VczTpXNOT?<JOr\ \ÞKC127JK    z autoinitalizes to input, T autoinitializes to 10 
 czT                         chop input into strings of length 10, returned as list of strings
V                            for each string N in this list:
            Or\ \Þ            randomly pick a char between ' ' (32) and 'Þ' (222)
           J                  and assign it to variable J
                  KC127       assign the DEL char to variable K
         ?<J      K           if J < K:
     XNOT              J       replace a random character in N with J
         ?<J      K           else:
     XNOT               K      replace a random character in N with K
    p                         print this string with no trailing newline
```

As is often the case, I feel that this is a bit of a naive method and may be improved upon. Usually I find something obvious while typing up the explanation but nothing jumped out at me this time.

Comment: Nice use of the delete char! One tip is that range operates on string too

Comment: @Maltysen Thanks! I have thought about your comment but I am not entirely sure where I could use it to save space. `OC\¾` is the same number of bytes as `O190`, and assigning K to the delete char doesn't save any space either.

Comment: @Maltysen So it took me a little bit but I realized what you meant and I've shaved off 2 bytes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

### [*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), <s>44</s> <s>46</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
rl5(?voooo/!|Ou+1Ox:@=?~o~oooo!
ol5(?v" ":/
o;!?l<
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=E4GwrAFA-Abg9guB6AhAHwPIFcDUBGDADwC4ABAXigD84bEUAoOcaGAIgAI3ikmBuFFBAAeIA)

This uses any ascii character near/above space for the random characters. This always edits the 6th character, unless it's the end of a string and that string's length isn't a multiple of 10. This has a 50% chance to remove the 7th character instead of editing the 6th.

#### Input

> The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) is a
>   technical standard for floating-point computation established in 1985
>   by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE). The
>   standard addressed many problems found in the diverse floating point
>   implementations that made them difficult to use reliably and portably.
>   Many hardware floating point units now use the IEEE 754 standard.

#### Output

> The IEE Standardfor Float$ng-Point Aithmetic (EEE 754) i a technicl
>   standar! for floa!ing-point!computati#n establised in 1985by the
>   Insitute of !lectrical#and Electrnics Engi!eers (IEE%). The st!ndard
>   add!essed man! problems#found in !he divers! floating oint
>   impl!mentation" that mad# them dif!icult to ue reliabl# and port!bly.
>   Many!hardware foating po#nt units %ow use th! IEEE 754"standard.

Edit: <s>This answer probably isn't always in the visible ascii range, editing...</s> Fixed.

Edit2: <s>Didn't see there needs to be a 50/50 chance to remove a character, editing again...</s> I believe everything is in order now :).

Comment: One more thing, someone suggested a random character so it's random now.

Comment: @n4melyh4xor, that was me! It is random :).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>78</s>  67 bytes

```perl6
{[~] map {~S/.**{(^.chars).pick}<(./{(' '..'~').pick x Bool.pick}/},.comb(10)}
```

```perl6
{[~] .comb(10)».&{~S/.**{10.rand}<(./{(' '..'~').pick x 2.rand}/}}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19anKpQZqaXbM2VW6mglpyfkqpgq1AdXReroJecn5ukYWigeWi3nlp1XbC@npZWtaGBXlFiXkqtjYaefrWGuoK6np56nbqmXkFmcrZChYIRRFa/tparOLFSAWzc@72L3PMVMvJzUxWSE0sUFSLzS9WLUhVSikrzshXf712skJZfpBBnaPD/PwA)

### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  [~]                  # reduce with string concatenation operator

  .comb(10)\           # take input and break it into chunks of up-to 10 chars

  ».\                 # on each of them call the following

  &{
    ~                  # Stringify the following

    S/                 # substituted
      .                # any char
        **             # repeated
           { 10.rand } # a random number of times

      <(               # ignore all of that

      .                # the char to be removed/replaced
    /{

      ( ' ' .. '~' ).pick  # choose a character
      x                    # string repeated
      2.rand               # zero or one times

    }/

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 21 bytes

```
smO,XdOTOr;\~.DdOTcQT
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smO%2CXdOTOr%3B%5C%7E.DdOTcQT&input=%22Go%20home%20cat%21%20You%27re%20drunk%21%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

The 75-byte applies the transformation to the first character of each group, and only picks from 2 random characters, such as in [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103394/60919) (which OP allowed):

```py
from random import*
f=lambda s:s and choice(['','a','b'])+s[1:10]+f(s[10:])
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DYm7DoQgEAD7@4o9G0AttCW5@j6A0lCsPCK5gzUbLPx6pJjMJNMiUwbG4rtSPonr@IqfP@bdIxhtoC9wByUX5CbELLCzC6sms616XewUZa9FW9VOTqXKKIcvwUE5gMM6w02X4ACer/J7D0q1Bw)

This is a recursive function which, every iteration, prepends either nothing, `'a'`, or `'b'`, and then calls itself with the first 10 characters sliced off. The final iteration short circuits at `s and` (an empty string is falsy), avoiding infinite recursion.

The result of all the separate calls are then concatenated, and returned to the context which called the function.

## 120 bytes

Of course, that feels a bit like cheating, so here's one which is completely random:

```py
from random import*;r=randint
def f(S):a=S[:10];R=r(0,len(a)-1);print(end=a[:R]+chr(r(32,126))*r(0,1)+a[R+1:]);f(S[10:])
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JYyxDoMgFEX3fgV16XtKE7FJBwhzdxyJAxGIphXMiw79eovpdE9uzr1HpLwwcsmXmJc101Yr0mcxp@3iQ2QRepRO91aKdlBGE7T8ExI4vAtUKxUPQvLaWWmGZpwICB4dF90TsT5lgY2zphFyQFXOrGgLHf9hhOqV2ZSXwEa3cfbN@40C87Sn97VCPH4)

Comment: Where did OP mention that the index of the replaced character can be 0?

Comment: @TuukkaX the comments have been removed to avoid clutter, but that's what the [jelly answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103394/60919) does, and OP said it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
₀ẇ⟑ẏ℅kP¤"℅℅Ȧ₴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoDhuofin5Hhuo/ihIVrUMKkXCLihIXihIXIpuKCtCIsIiIsIlwiR28gaG9tZSBjYXQhIFlvdSdyZSBkcnVuayFcIiJd)

```
₀ẇ            # Chunks of length 10...
  ⟑           # Over each...
           Ȧ  # Replace at ...
   ẏ℅         # random index in the input
          ℅   # A random item of...
         ℅    # A random item of...
     kP       # Printable ascii
       ¤"     # Or the empty string
            ₴ #
```

Comment: Looks like this gets applied once to the input as a whole when it should be applied to each grouping of 10 characters in the input.

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed..

Comment: It also looks like it only has a `1/96` chance to remove a character when it should be a `1/2` chance.

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed..

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15 14</s>  13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) 13 characters

```
2X
s⁵µ¢1¦ṫ¢µ€
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MlgKc-KBtcK1wqIxwqbhuavCosK14oKs&input=&args=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)**

Replaces or removes the first of every ten characters including that of the last 1-9 if there is such a chunk. Chooses from the, admittedly small, subset  of characters: `1`; `2`.

#### How?

```
2X         - Link 1, flip a coin: no arguments
 X         - random choice from
2          - 2 (treated as the integers [1,2])

s⁵µ¢1¦ṫ¢µ€ - Main link: string of printable ASCII
s⁵         - split (s) into chunks of size ten (⁵)
  µ     µ  - monadic chain separation 
         € - for each chunk
   ¢       -     last link as a nilad
    1¦     -     apply to index 1 (replace 1st of the 10 char chunk with the chosen integer)
       ¢   -     last link as a nilad
      ṫ    - tail - if it was 1 this has no effect (50%)
                  - if it was 2 this discards the replaced character (50%)
           - implicit print
```

---

To choose from all of printable ASCII rather than just `1` and `2` (still replacing or removing the 1st character of each chunk) in 21 bytes:

```
s⁵µ32r126¤ỌX¤1¦ṫ2X¤µ€
```

---

For a [fully random version](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OTVSKzMx4buMWDsKCnPigbXCteG5meKBtVjCpMKp4bmWMljCpMS_4bmZwq5DwqTCteKCrA&input=&args=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) (50/50 remove/replace, uniform random printable ASCII, and a uniformly random character location within each chunk) I have 30 bytes (probably non-optimal):

```
95R+31ỌX;

s⁵µṙ⁵X¤©Ṗ2X¤Ŀṙ®C¤µ€
```

This rotates each chunk left by a random amount, pops the last character off and then calls a random one of the first two links, one of which is empty and the other which concatenates with a random printable ASCII character; it then rotates the chunk right again.

Comment: This really goes against the spirit of the post

Comment: @Maltysen - OP said all these things are fine.

Comment: Where? I don't see anything in the comments or OP.

Comment: @Maltysen they have been cleared.

Comment: ok then, sorry about that. Can you make a trivial edit so I can undownvote you?

Comment: There was a comment explicitly saying we could choose from 2 characters AND that they did not want to put it into the Question body.

Comment: @Maltysen FWIW I have added a fully random version (although I'm sure it could be shorter!)

Comment: OP has stated that the least amount of characters wins. Jelly doesn't get affected by this though, unless it has multibyte characters.

Comment: @TuukkaX yeah, each byte is mapped to a character (one of the byte instructions has two possible characters, either a line feed or a pilcrow - which also has no effect); many of them would require more than one byte to represent with unicode (but it does not specify a byte count of the characters in a specific encoding).

Comment: ...or each character maps to a byte

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, <s>135</s> 139 bytes**

Edit: Forgot to use `partition-all` instead of `partition`.

```
(fn[i](apply str(flatten(map #(let[r rand-int [b e](split-at(r 9)%)][b(if(<(rand)0.5)""(char(+(r 25)97)))(rest e)])(partition-all 10 i)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(def f (fn[i]
         (->> i
              (partition-all 10)
              (map #(let [[begin end] (split-at (rand-int 9) %)]
                      [begin (if (< 0.5 (rand)) "" (char (+(rand-int 25)97))) (rest end)]))
              flatten
              (apply str))))
```

Man those function names are long... Anyway, it splits input into partitions of 10 characters, splits them at random point into two halves, randomly injects an empty string or a random character between them and discards the first character of the 2nd half.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 133 Bytes (129 characters)

```
StringReplacePart[#,Table[If[(r=RandomInteger)[]<1,"",FromCharacterCode@r@128],c=⌊StringLength@#/10⌋],Array[{g=10#-9+r@9,g}&,c]]&
```

76 characters to write the names of 8 functions :/

Using the `⌊..⌋` instead of `Floor[]` saves 5 characters, 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, <s>188</s> <s>186</s> <s>184</s> 114 characters

```
from random import*
s=input()
for c in[s[i:i+10]for i in range(0,len(s),10)]:print(end=choice(["","x","y"])+c[1:])
```

<s>Seems too long. Could probably be shortened a lot with a lambda.</s>

Apparently the OP has allowed choosing the random character from a list of two characters and the index of the character to be replaced can be a constant. After the modifications, my answer would've looked exactly the same as [@FlipTacks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105194/41754) Python submission, so this is the form I'm staying with.

[@FlipTack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60919/fliptack) saved 5 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 129 bytes

```
def f(s):f=id(s)%9+1;print(''.join(j[0:f-1]+chr(33+id(s)%94)*(id(s)//10%2)+j[f:]for j in [s[i:i+10]for i in range(0,len(s),10)]))
```

In order to save some bytes, instead of importing Python's random module, I just did some modulo operations on the id of the string, which should be different every time. For example the program will decide whether or not to remove a char or replace one based on whether or not `id(string)//10` is even (I integer divide by 10 as the last digit will always be even).

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 52 bytes

```ruby
gsub(/.{10}/){_1[rand 0..9]=[*" "..?~,""].sample
_1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5BjlLsgqWlJWm6FjdN0otLkzT09aoNDWr1NavjDaOLEvNSFAz09CxjbaO1lBSU9PTs63SUlGL1ihNzC3JSueINayF6oUYs2OWer5CRn5uqkJxYoqgQmV-qXpSqkFJUmpetCFEBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 46 bytes

```
Fi(a<>t){IRR2YiRARR#iRCPAEL{YiRARR#ix}b:bAEy}b
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaShhPD50KXtJUlIyWWlSQVJSI2lSQ1BBRUx7WWlSQVJSI2l4fWI6YkFFeX1iIiwiIiwiIiwiXCJHbyBob21lIGNhdCEgWW91J3JlIGRydW5rIVwiIl0=)

How?

```
Fi(a<>t){IRR2YiRARR#iRCPAEL{YiRARR#ix}b:bAEy}b
Fi      {                                   }  - For each in
      t                                        - Var for 10
   a<>t                                        - Split input into 10 pieces
         I                                     - If truthy
          RR2                                  - 0 or 1
             Y                                   - Yank (equivalent to (y:a)):
               RA                                 - Replace item in at index
              i                                   - First input
                 RR#i                             - Random int from 0 to length of input
                     RCPA                         - Random Printable ASCII character
                         EL{         }         - Else
                            Y                    - Yank:
                              RA                  - Replace item in at index
                             i                    - First input
                                RR#i              - Random int from 0 to length of input
                                    x             - Empty string
                                      b:       - Assign b to
                                        bAEy   - Append y to b
                                             b - Output b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
TôεžQΩæΩ9ÝΩǝ?
```

Also (potentially) modifies the last part if it's less than 10 characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9vc2FiaWX//1TDtM61xb5RzqnDps6pOcOdzqnHnT///0dvIGhvbWUgY2F0ISBZb3UncmUgZHJ1bmsh/y0tbm8tbGF6eQ) or [see 10 example outputs at once](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9vc2FiaWX/VEb/VMO0zrXFvlHOqcOmzqk5w53OqcedP/99XMK2P/9HbyBob21lIGNhdCEgWW91J3JlIGRydW5rIf8tLW5vLWxhenk).

**Explanation:**

```python
Tô             # Split the (implicit) input-string into parts of size 10
               # (where the trailing part is potentially smaller)
  ε            # Foreach over the parts:
   žQ          #  Push the printable ASCII string constant
     Ω         #  Pop and push a random character from it
      æ        #  Get the powerset of this character, resulting in a pair of an empty
               #  string "" and the character
       Ω       #  Pop and push a random item from this pair
        9Ý     #  Push list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
          Ω    #  Pop and push a random digit from this list
           ǝ   #  Replace the character at that (0-based) index with the chosen ASCII
               #  character or the empty string
               #  (if the index is ≥ the length, it does nothing)
            ?  #  Pop and print the modified part
```